# approximate time for indexing a conference proceeding

Tags: indexing

Maybe some of you could help me with this matter based on your experiences. I presented an article for an IEEE congress which was held in March of this year, and accordingly, to their webpage, the proceedings will be indexed on IEEE Xplore. I have checked that previous versions of this congress, for example, the one held in 2018, was indexed in Scopus. We are on August, and still, the proceedings do not appear on IEEE Xplore either in Scopus. Is it normal to take that long time for the articles to get indexed? By the way, we sent the final versions already ready to be put on the conference proceedings, so there was no need for a new review for style.

Also, I got an article accepted from a journal which is also indexed in Scopus, which has a monthly basis. For what I saw on the website of this journal, which is Q3 or Q4, from the 30 articles published, only two are appearing actually in Scopus. The articles from July are completed; why is that? Did maybe Scopus decided not to put the other articles?

Bottom line, should I contact the editors?

It might sound like particular cases, but I was not able to find any information about the time-lapse from presentation or publication to appear on Scopus or other sites like IEEE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible for a significant amount of time to elapse between the conference and appearance of articles on IEEE Xplore. For example, [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7860448) is a link to one of my papers which appeared in the proceedings of an IEEE conference that was held in **September 2016**, and it was **added to IEEE Xplore in the end of February 2017**.

Note that you can actually see both the **Date of Conference** and **Date Added to IEEE *Xplore*** on that page as well, right below the abstract. So you could also look up some articles from previous editions of the specific congress that you went to, and see how much time it took for that congress in previous years (but of course it doesn't have to be the same this year).